# What can I do with the $db variable in mysql_select_db("database", $db);

Tags: php, database, variables

What does the `$db` variable do and what can I do with it after writing it after the first parameter? I have searched for an answer but your answers are almost always better.

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("database", $db);
?>
```

I ask this question because I see people using the `$db` tag a lot with representing the database. They do things like for example this: `$db->query("SELECT * FROM questions")` or `die($db->error);`.

Comment: Learn about object-oriented programming.

Comment: Can't do that much with that answer Chosen Wann, nice and funny username BTW (:

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` functions anymore; they're deprecated. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Your two examples confuse the old mysql_* function approach with object handles from PDO/mysqli. At this point it would make sense for you to read through a [complete tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), not switch between multiple introductions.

Comment: Really? Explain please. What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $db a reserved variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924309/is-db-a-reserved-variable-in-php)

Comment: Please consult the fine manual to learn what you can do with X.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not include a problem.  It simply asks for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$db` is usually for database connection. It provides connection link to database, identifies the connection and provides database object. When you use `mysql_*` functions, you can define last parameter as connection variable. You use it to indentify connection, so multiple mysql connections don't mix up.